# Can an application written for Windows 7 run on Windows embedded standard 7 OS?

Tags: windows-7-embedded

Looking to develop Win 7 embedded. However, 3rd party APIs run on standard Win 7 OS.
Can I run these APIs on Win 7 Embedded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Embedded does support the regular Win32 APIs.

But your embedded device will need to be an x86 device (as opposed to ARM, or SuperH).